# Android: Access AudioRecord.Builder class from JNI level similar to AudioRecord

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, audiorecord

What is right way to access [AudioRecord.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.Builder) at the JNI level?

Similar to `AudioRecord` class.

```c
(jclass)jni_env->NewGlobalRef(jni_env->FindClass("android/media/AudioRecord"));
```

ex:

```
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord.Builder()
         .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
         .setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
                 .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                 .setSampleRate(32000)
                 .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO)
                 .build())
         .setBufferSizeInBytes(2*minBuffSize)
         .build();
```

Comment: What is the purpose? Or what are you trying to achieve and why? This helps us answer questions, currently, it's like you just want another way to setup something in Java but using JNI, which besides doing this for fun, makes little other sense. JNI access the native libraries etc, so you can't simply take java code and change it to the equivalent JNI as easily as you would expect. But again what are you attempting to gain by this?

Comment: I am trying to to get AudioRecord instance at JNI and use AudioRecord.Builder#setPrivacySensitive(boolean) API.. Similar to -- >> 
 https://github.com/r3gis3r/CSipSimple/blob/fd1e332c656f76b7a10b0eb161ba582e38d06249/jni/pjsip/android_sources/pjmedia/src/pjmedia-audiodev/android_jni_dev.cpp#L635

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 4):

Besides my above comment, you can easily find out these types of things as android is open source.

So first take a look at the android [AudioRecord](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b267554/media/java/android/media/AudioRecord.java) source code. In there you will notice the `AudioRecord` constructor calls a method called `native_start` as well as other native methods to setup the audio via JNI.

[image]

browsing further you will see a comment referencing the AudioRecord.cpp file.

The cpp file can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/jni/android_media_AudioRecord.cpp) you might need to make sure you take a look at the one that matches your android version, I just picked anyone from a Google search. In there you will of course see how the `AudioRecord` class functions natively, as well as what methods it exposes to JNI etc

[image]

With the above you can essentially see the `AudioRecord` java class essentially interacts with the native code, which is what you want to achieve

**UPDATE:**

So from your comment you can do exactly this. The issue is I just took random links so sorry maybe my fault.

If you look at the master branch source code you will find what you are looking for.

In the [AudioRecord.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/AudioRecord.java) in the master branch you will find it accepts a `AudioAttributes` class in the constructor, which undergoes some filtering further down and then finally `native_setup` is called with these filtered audio attributes`mAudioAttributes`:

[image]

You could further see how ithese attributes are being applied in the native code [AudioRecord.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_media_AudioRecord.cpp)  by following the trail of the `jaa` variable passed into the `native_setup` via `AudioRecord.java` which maps to the native method `android_media_AudioRecord_setup` :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking for FindClass way of class access of AudioRecord.Builder .. similar to --->> https://github.com/r3gis3r/CSipSimple/blob/fd1e332c656f76b7a10b0eb161ba582e38d06249/jni/pjsip/android_sources/pjmedia/src/pjmedia-audiodev/android_jni_dev.cpp#L635.

Comment: What have you tried? [`AudioAttributes`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/AudioAttributes.java) is within the same folder, the Builder class is a static inner class so I think you would do something like `(jclass)jni_env->NewGlobalRef(jni_env->FindClass("android/media/AudioAttributes$Builder"))` but I can't be certain as haven't tested it myself but basically you want to access Builder which is a static class in AudioAttributes.

Comment: Yeah will check this way -->> (jclass)jni_env->NewGlobalRef(jni_env->FindClass("android/media/AudioRecord$Builder")); Was looking if someone already tried and made it work.